# Integrated DMCA badges are not show up on all pages

Tags: wordpress, badge

I have integrated DMCA badge through the Wordpress plugin, but the badge is not showing for all pages.

Any solutions on how to fix it?

[costoffliving.com](https://costoffliving.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to hear you're having troubles with the plugin.

- Can I ask which version of wordpress you're using?
- Can you tell me which page you're having trouble with?

The DMCA.com Wordpress Badge plugin (https://www.dmca.com/WordPress/) works with the wordpress templating system.

- You can choose which templates the badges show up on by clicking on
  the "Settings" page
- You can also always just copy and past the badge / embed code into an
  html widget and drag and drop that wherever you want.

Screenshot of the dmca.com wordpress plugin settings:
[image: screenshot of the dmca.com wordpress plugin settings]

Thanks
DMCA.com Support